# Why does this type alias not compile (Scala)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get code like the following to work:

```
abstract class Vec[Self <: Vec[Self,T], T] {
    this : Self =>
    def *(y : Self) : Self
}

abstract class LA[T] {
  type V <: Vec[V, T]
}

object typetest2 {
    def doesntcompile[L <: LA[Double]](x : L#V, y : L#V) : Unit = {
        val z = x * y
    }

    def compiles[V <: Vec[V,_]](x : V, y : V) : Unit = {
        val z = x * y
    }
}
```

But the compiler gives

```
[error]  found   : y.type (with underlying type L#V)
[error]  required: _9.V
[error]         val z = x * y
[error]                     ^
```

Is this a failure of the type checker or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting question. I tried to get it to compile but failed. But I found that it also does not compile for a much simpler example: If you make LA non-generic and non-abstract, and replace `type V` with `class MyDouble(d: Double) extends Vec[MyDouble, Double]`, and then even remove the generics of `doesntcompile` and change the type of `x` and `y` to `LA#MyDouble`, it does fail with pretty much the same compile-error for me. Here's what I tried: http://pastie.org/9595425  Note: You can even get rid of `LB` and still get the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not certain there's no workaround for this particular case, the compiler can't generically tell that two path-dependent types are equal even when they are.

You can generally solve such cases by adding an additional type parameter:

```
def compiles2[V1 <: Vec[V1, _], L <: LA[Double]{type V = V1}](x: L#V, y: L#V) = {
  val z = x * y
}
```

In some cases you might need to require an implicit `=:=` or `Leibniz` (Scalaz) to get the compiler to pass evidence that two types are equal down the chain.